# Phone Number Link Detection on Mobile Device

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am creating a native app for iOS with Jquery Mobile and Phonegap. Within the app, I dynamically load data with ajax. Some of the included data are strings of numbers that automatically add a tel: link to the span containing the string. I need to remove the link from being assigned to it. I have tried adding `<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />` to the head and tried adding x-apple-data-detectors="false" to the span. Neither have worked. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add this meta header to your page, to prevent it automatically creating the `tel:` links

`<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />`

See the Safari [documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/PhoneLinks.html)

Comment: @user29354 You said in a comment to Noogen that the browsers are detecting the 10 digit number. What browsers are you trying? Are you seeing this on desktop browsers as well independently of PhoneGap? Can you post the AJAX code and a sample of the data?

Comment: It seems that there was something wrong with the string itself. The checked off solution with meta format-detection was the only thing that was required. Thanks to all for your time.

Answer (score -1):

Add meta tag to your html and add code inside of webViewDidStartLoad method in iOS MainViewController.m

```
(void) webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView*)theWebView
{

    // disable telephone detection, basically <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    theWebView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeAll & !UIDataDetectorTypePhoneNumber;
    return [super webViewDidStartLoad:theWebView];
}
```

Comment: The question is PhoneGap specific. It's unnecessary to edit the PhoneGap container to achieve this.

Comment: I am afraid the above solution did not work. This issue is happening in my phonegap build as well as in every browser I test. Somehow the browsers are detecting this 10 digit string and automatically assigning a link to it.